# Odoo 10 - Translation

Tags: odoo, translation, odoo-10, po

I have developed a custom module, using English for all the records.

I want to include a localized translation file for a local language (which happens to be Spanish).

I have learnt [here in the Odoo doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/translations.html) that I need to export a .PO file using "New Language (Empty translation template)".

1. I can read the .PO file and understand where do I have the translated files, but my question is, apart from the obvious translation part, how can you "tell" Odoo that you are adding a translation for Spanish?
2. I understand that the .PO file must be put inside i18n folder in the module.
   But which name shall I gave to it for spanish?
3. What shall be added to the file to tell "Odoo" it is a translation for Spanish?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to rename your file to `es.po` and put it into `your_module\i18n\es.po`.

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

After you rename your file to `es.po`and put it into `your_module\i18n\es.po`

1. Go to -> Settings and active `Deactivate the developer mode`
2. And go to `Load a Translation`[image: Load a Translation]  and select `Spanish` and checked `overwrite exisiting terms`

Comment: Why do I need to load the translation in the GUI? Is it not enough to (re)install the module?

Comment: Because de language by default is English

Comment: There is no need to load a translation as the module installs the translated (in this case spanish) language that will be automatically applied if user language matches.